# Get sys for save_system simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Disclaimer: I'm not a professional simulink/matlab programmer

If I've opened simulink and created a model, then i want to save it from the commandline in matlab. The `save_system` works, but I also want to specify a filename, for this i need to use `save_system(sys, newsysname.slx)`

I can't seem to find a function to get `sys`. How can I get the same sys as save_system() uses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`gcs`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/gcs.html) to get the current system or [`bdroot`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/bdroot.html) to get the top-level of the model. [`find_system`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/find_system.html) may also be useful.